# Collapse rows and keep highest/lowest dates

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rows

I want to collapse multiple rows with admission dates, discharge dates and causes of stay.
But i only want to keep the  earliest admission date and the latest discharge date grouped by the ID and the cause of stay.

My dataframe looks like this:

structure(list(AdmissionDate = structure(c(16709, 16710, 16713,
16714, 16715, 16729, 16730, 16731, 16735, 16741, 16742, 16787,
16790, 16792, 16797, 16798, 16799), class = "Date"), DischargeDate = structure(c(16709,
16710, 16713, 16714, 16715, 16729, 16730, 16731, 16735, 16741,
16742, 16787, 16790, 16792, 16797, 16798, 16799), class = "Date"),
ID = c(1010091262, 1010091262, 1010091262, 1010091262, 1010091262,
1010091262, 1010091262, 1010091262, 1010091262, 1010091262,
1010091262, 1640300380, 1640300380, 1640300380, 1640300380,
1640300380, 1640300380), CauseOfStay = c("Folge: Hirninfarkt",
"Folge: Hirninfarkt", "Folge: Hirninfarkt", "Folge: Hirninfarkt",
"Folge: Hirninfarkt", "Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl",
"Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl", "Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl",
"Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl", "Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl",
"Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl", "Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl",
"Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl", "Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl",
"Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl", "Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl",
"Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl")), row.names = c(1L,
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 60L, 61L, 62L,
63L, 64L, 65L), class = "data.frame")

The output should contain 3 rows with the earliest admission date, latest discharge date grouped by the cause of stay and the ID.

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that you want to reduce an `n`-row frame to just 1 row. Is this grouped by `Cause of stay`? Is there a "patient id" field that should also be used for gropuing? Do you want to only group overlapping dates? Are you columns really strings, or have you already converted them to `Date` objects in R (a critical step)? Finally, the spaces in column names and data makes it a bit more difficult to just try to use this data. Can you please post using the output from `dput`, perhaps `dput(head(x))`? It removes ambiguity and makes it much simpler for us to test and use.

Comment: I have edited my question and apologize for the unclear description.

Comment: Thanks! Using @langtang's answer, replacing the variable names and changing `group_by(\`Cause of Stay\`)` to `group_by(ID, CauseOfStay)` and it gives you your three rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how would I go about just modifying the dataframe? Because there are several other columns which I would like to keep which get lost during the summarize call.

Comment: `But i only want to keep the earliest admission date and the latest discharge date grouped by the ID and the cause of stay.` langtang's answer (with updated column names) returns four columns: `ID`, `CauseOfStay`, `AdmissionDate`, and `DischargeDate`. You give us four columns, explicitly say you only want to keep those four columns, so why are you expecting something else? BTW, "modifying the dataframe" makes no sense, as you are changing the overall "shape" of the frame. This is a summarizing operation which by definition changes the shape (and should likely leave the original intact).

Comment: (Thanks for the sample data, btw, that is great!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group_by / summarize.. You can add your patient identifier (`ID`) to the `group_by()` clause to allow different patients to have different summarized rows, for the same Cause of Stay

```
dat %>%
  group_by(ID, CauseOfStay) %>%
  summarize(AdmissionDate = min(AdmissionDate, na.rm=T),
            DischargeDate = max(DischargeDate, na.rm=T))
```

Output:

```
          ID CauseOfStay                       AdmissionDate DischargeDate
       <dbl> <chr>                             <date>        <date>       
1 1010091262 Folge: Hirninfarkt                2015-10-01    2015-10-07   
2 1010091262 Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl 2015-10-21    2015-11-03   
3 1640300380 Schädigung: Hirn, anoxisch, aonkl 2015-12-18    2015-12-30
```